# mysql query too slow

Tags: mysql, performance

My simple MYSQL query is too slow, my table has 550k row data and based on Innodb, when I run query as:

```
mysql> select count(*) from program;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   542500 |
+----------+
1 row in set (19.16 sec)
```

my table is defined as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `program` (
  `id` int(32) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `apik` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `programId` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `created` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `style` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=552331 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I found that information:

```
mysql> show global status like 'key%';
+------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name          | Value   |
+------------------------+---------+
| Key_blocks_not_flushed | 0       |
| Key_blocks_unused      | 1714736 |
| Key_blocks_used        | 0       |
| Key_read_requests      | 0       |
| Key_reads              | 0       |
| Key_write_requests     | 0       |
| Key_writes             | 0       |
+------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: What query runs slow?

Comment: Do you have indexes on columns that you join and aggregate on?

Comment: I didn't jion or aggregate any table. i dump this table and upload this table into another server, every thing is ok. this query only use 0.5s. this server is same as the original server(same hardware, same mysql,same os).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem here is InnoDB

MyISAM stores the total row count, InnoDB won't do this so it have to make a full scan, which takes quite long. Look if the manual kann help you:

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table because
>   concurrent transactions might “see” different numbers of rows at the
>   same time. To process a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t statement, InnoDB scans
>   an index of the table, which takes some time if the index is not
>   entirely in the buffer pool. If your table does not change often,
>   using the MySQL query cache is a good solution. To get a fast count,
>   you have to use a counter table you create yourself and let your
>   application update it according to the inserts and deletes it does. If
>   an approximate row count is sufficient, [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-table-status.html) can be used.
>   See Section 14.2.12.1, [“InnoDB Performance Tuning Tips”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-tuning.html).